# How to implement Post/Redirect/Get using Python with CGI

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, cgi

I've recently began making an Amazon Linux EC2 LAMP server using Python CGI. I'm making a simple script that stores a name submitted from a text box to a MySQL table and displays it from any other browser. I came across a problem where any browser I'm on asks to resend the data on refresh. For example, Firefox sends,

> To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.

I went looking for ways to fix this and one of the ways I found was to use a Post/Redirect/Get design pattern. I haven't found any examples that use Python and CGI together, and I'm at a bit of a loss as to how this works - however, I think after implementing it I'll understand a bit better.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


print "Content-Type: text/html"

#print "Location: http://34.212.128.254/hellopython.py"

print """
    <title>NameSample</title>
    <form action="hellopython.py" method="post">

     First Name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="off"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
"""

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

pastName = form.getvalue("firstname")
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="DEFINITELY_NOT_LOCALHOST",    # your host, usually localhost
                 user="INSERT_USER",         # your username
                 passwd="INSERT_PASSWORD",  # your password
                 db="users")        # name of the data base
    cur = db.cursor()

    if form.getvalue("firstname") != None:

    cur.execute("truncate user")

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO user VALUE('"+pastName+"',1)")

    db.commit();

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user")

    for row in cur.fetchall():
        print row[0]

    db.close()

else:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user")

    for row in cur.fetchall():
        print row[0]

    db.close()
```

I understand that not all of this is important, but hey, I'm a novice and it's probably best I don't omit anything.